# ng-repeat for key value pairs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can some one help me with formulating Angular ng-repeat for creating the formatted output from the json below

```
Name: David Smith
Phone : 734-323-4323
Email : abcd@yahoo.com
Skill : Java, ASP, Oracle
CanWorkAt: Los Angeles, San Franscisco, Santa Clara
Reference: Micheal
```

My json object is below

```
{"ObjectId":"1234",
    "keyvalues":[
            {"key":"Name","value":"David Smith"},
            {"key":"Phone","value":"734-323-4323"},
            {"key":"Email","value":"abcd@yahoo.com"},
            {"key":"Skill","value":"Java"},
            {"key":"Skill","value":"ASP"},
            {"key":"Skill","value":"Oracle"},
            {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"Los Angeles"},
            {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"San Franscisco"},
            {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"Santa Clara"},
            {"key":"Reference","value":"Micheal"}
             ]
}
```

Comment: What did your try after reading https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat?

Comment: ng-repeat below lists all the keys. 
   <div class="item" ng-repeat="keyValue in object.keyvalues">
    {{keyValue.key }} :  {{keyValue.value }} 
   </div>

Answer (score 0):

script.js

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('ngRepeat', ['ngAnimate']).controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.objects = 
  [
    { "ObjectId":"1234",
      "keyvalues":
      [
          {"key":"Name","value":"David Smith"},
          {"key":"Phone","value":"734-323-4323"},
          {"key":"Email","value":"abcd@yahoo.com"},
          {"key":"Skill","value":"Java"},
          {"key":"Skill","value":"ASP"},
          {"key":"Skill","value":"Oracle"},
          {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"Los Angeles"},
          {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"San Franscisco"},
          {"key":"CanWorkAt","value":"Santa Clara"},
          {"key":"Reference","value":"Micheal"}
      ]
    }
  ];
});
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<body ng-app="ngRepeat">
  <div ng-controller="repeatController">
  <ul>
    <ol class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="obj in objects | filter:q as results">
       ObjectId: {{obj.ObjectId}} 
      <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="key in  obj.keyvalues ">
        {{key.key}} {{key.value}}
      </li>
    </ol>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you face here is that:

- The json sample you gave did not wrap itself in square brackets/ as arrays. With json objects there is only one way to access data, i.e. through the key-value pairs' key.
- And ng-repeat only go through arrays and iterables, so no it won't do it.

The solution is for each column that can have multiple values, you convert them to array first. Same goes with the outer employ/ programmer object if you have multiple employee objects you have to wrap them in arrays.